# Any infinite non abelian group with exactly $ \phi (n) $ elements of order $n$ for every $ n $?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, abelian-groups, infinite-groups

I am wondering if there is any infinite non abelian group with exactly $ \phi (n) $ elements of order $n$ for every $ n $

If not, is there any thing like if for each $ n $ the group contains $ \phi (n) $ elements of order $n$ then the group is abelian?

Just some random thoughts. Does anyone have any examples?
If not, then do you have any tool to prove the later part? Please don't disclose the proof just let me have some hints.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @lulu I've corrected that.

Comment: @reuns Are you sure there is some? Or asking me to investigate?

Comment: Try $G$ times a free group

Comment: What if ${}{}{}{}{}n=0$?

Comment: @reuns I would really appreciate if you add some more details, or some pdf s. As I am unable to grasp.

Comment: @markvs Pardon me, I meant n = 1, 2, 3 ...

Comment: I expect you wanted to assume that this is a torsion group, to avoid easy examples (like direct products).

Comment: @lulu if you got any direct product examples can you please write it down?

Comment: @reuns already gave you one.  If, say, $\mathbb U$ denotes the complex roots of unity, that would be an abelian group with your property.  So just take $G=\mathbb U\times F_2$ where, of course, $F_2$ denotes the free group on $2$ letters.  Clearly $G$ is non-abelian, and clearly it passes your test.  Of course, $G$ also has many elements without finite order.

Comment: If $G$ is torsion then it is in fact the roots of unity.

Comment: @reuns  Is that obvious?

Comment: any $a,b$ are in the cyclic subgroup generated by an element of order $order(a)order(b)$ @lulu

Comment: @reuns  Oh, right.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone